# OSX Terminal: How to figure out network connection is WIFI or LAN?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to find out how the system is connected to the internet using Wifi or LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the `networksetup` utility to list all current services available:

```
$~ networksetup -listallnetworkservices
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Thunderbolt Ethernet
Display Ethernet
Display FireWire
Wi-Fi
iPhone USB
Bluetooth PAN
Thunderbolt Bridge
```

Or you could list the service order:

```
$~ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Thunderbolt Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Device: en5)

(2) Display Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Display Ethernet, Device: en6)

(3) Display FireWire
(Hardware Port: Display FireWire, Device: fw0)

(4) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)

(5) iPhone USB
(Hardware Port: iPhone USB, Device: en4)

(6) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en3)

(7) Thunderbolt Bridge
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge, Device: bridge0)
```

Then you can query each service to see if it's connected/configured e.g.

```
$~ networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi
DHCP Configuration
IP address: 10.0.0.120
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 10.0.0.138
Client ID: 
IPv6: Automatic
IPv6 IP address: none
IPv6 Router: none
Wi-Fi ID: 6c:40:08:a9:62:50
```

Comment: is it possible to write a script for this? or a one-liner? and yes!! Many thanks your answer is satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -C1 $(route get default | grep interface | awk '{print $2}')
```

It checks which interface is currently used as default route and then looks up its hardware information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep -C1 $(netstat -nr | grep ^default | grep -o "\s\S\+$")
```

---

Basically it consist `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -nr | grep ^default
default            192.168.46.1       UGSc          399        0     en0
```

which gives you the `default` gateway IP address via which you connect to the internet. The relevant part is the last column which gives you name of the network interface (`en0`).

Since OS X is using the same name of interface for WiFi and wired ethernet (which is different for other Unixes), it's not possible to distinguish it by its name.

So this extra command should give you a clue which device it is:

```
$ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep -C1 en0
(3) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)
```